# How to post Form Based Authentication

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to get form based authentication to work and came across only 1 reference on the web that indicated the url was j_security_check and the parameters are j_username and j_password.  There is no mention of this in any of the quarkus docs.

Am I missing something or is the documentation lacking this critical piece of information?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're totally right about the lack of documentation on that, despite this, I've consolidated some information.

### To make the authentication

Create a HTML form which perform the POST to `/j_security_check`

[login.html](http://fxapps.blogspot.com/2019/12/quarkus-application-with-form.html)

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="j_username"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="j_username" required>

        <label for="j_password"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="j_password" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

A CURL example

```
$ curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8080/j_security_check -d 'j_username=admin&j_password=admin'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
location: http://localhost:8080/index.html
content-length: 0
set-cookie: quarkus-credential=DPeFtSios6kIpWpJw6BpCfId3+MT151H3yPOc5VzfYdrdO6oRcE+dy18IL0KMeFx; Path=/
```

### References about the login mechanism

I didn't found any additional doc explaining the login steps but I did some greps on quarkus source code and found [this file](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/4c323ae72d2466c72ada1d2fbf773653748a4a84/extensions/vertx-http/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/vertx/http/runtime/security/FormAuthenticationMechanism.java#L1) which seems to handle the `/j_security_check` endpoint, looks likes there is no way to customize this path, or the parameters names, yet. This file is present on the dependency `quarkus-vertx-http-1.10.5.Final.jar`

```
public class FormAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FormAuthenticationMechanism.class);

    public static final String DEFAULT_POST_LOCATION = "/j_security_check";
```

An interesting fact, a file with the same name, but with a more advanced code can also be found at[undertow project](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/1a10af565a90993ca2bac6ec89502941facd0139/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/security/impl/FormAuthenticationMechanism.java#L1), the path can be customized there.

Comment: The Form Based Authentication can be configured by setting the `quarkus.http.auth.form.*` properties.

They are described on this page: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication